# Globally changing shortcuts' drive letter?

Tags: windows-xp, shortcuts

On my XP (SP3) PC I'm about to move 'My Documents' (sometimes quaintly but confusingly called 'Terry's Documents' from C:\Docs to I:\Docs.

What is the recommended simplest (and safest) method of renaming the thousands of shortcuts that will be affected please?

I will still have major work to change other references (not least for all my Macro Express Pro macros and AutoHotkey scripts) but I'll tackle those later.

-- 
Terry, East Grinstead, UK

Answer (score 0):

Looks like PowerShell might be able to change shortcut properties: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484560/editing-shortcut-lnk-properties-with-powershell).

Comment: Thanks but I'm no techie or programmer so I'm afraid both that and Shortcut.exe were over my head.I could copy/paste and run a VBS or other script if someone can point me to one please. Ideally one which allows me to enter my targets until I'm confident enough to let it loose on the entire PC. Even better, a standalone program.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a VBScript expert, but this script seems to do the trick:

```
Const DESKTOP = &H10&

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(DESKTOP)
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("Change wallpaper.lnk")
Set objShellLink = objFolderItem.GetLink

objShellLink.Path = Replace (objShellLink.Path, "I:\", "C:\")
objShellLink.Save()
```

That will take a shortcut on your desktop (called "Change wallpaper.lnk"), and replace the `C:\` in its target with `I:\`. Obviously you'll want to iterate over lots of shortcuts...

Comment: Thanks, I'll use that as a basis for working - after doing some reading on VBS basics! [How do I start a new para here? <Enter> just sends the post prematurely.]